# Error after .configure to install Omnet++ 5.6.1 on Mac

Tags: macos, omnet++

I am trying to get Omnet++ to run on my Mac and i am at the following step:

**3.6.** Configuring and Building OMNeT++
Check configure.user to make sure it contains the settings you need. In most cases
you don’t need to change anything in it.
In the top-level OMNeT++ directory, type:
$ ./configure
The configure script detects installed software and configuration of your system.
It writes the results into the Makefile.inc file, which will be read by the makefiles
during the build process.

**But my log shows me this and i don't understand what i did wrong or where i should make changes:**

```html
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0
configure: -----------------------------------------------
configure: reading configure.user for your custom settings
configure: -----------------------------------------------
checking for icc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for icpc... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking for ranlib... ranlib
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
checking whether g++ supports -fno-omit-frame-pointer... yes
checking whether g++ supports -Wl,--no-as-needed... no
checking whether g++ supports -Wl,--as-needed... no
checking if shared libs need -fPIC... no
checking for dlopen with CFLAGS="" LIBS=""... yes
checking if --export-dynamic linker option is supported/needed... test failed
checking for flags needed to link with static libs containing simple modules... -all_load
configure: NOTE: Use the following syntax when linking with static libraries
configure: containing simple modules and other dynamically registered components:
configure:    g++ ... -Wl,-all_load <libs>  ...
checking whether linker supports -rpath... yes
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... none needed
checking whether yytext is a pointer... no
checking for make... make
checking for perl... perl
checking for swig... not found
checking for math with CFLAGS="" LIBS=""... yes
checking for standard C++ lib with CFLAGS="" LIBS="-lstdc++"... yes
checking for dlopen with CFLAGS="" LIBS=""... yes
checking for qmake... no
checking for qmake-qt5... no
checking for qmake5... no
configure: error: Qtenv cannot find qmake -- maybe it is not in the PATH or has some exotic name (tested names were: qmake qmake-qt5 qmake5) - disabling Qtenv. You can try setting the QT_PATH variable in configure.user to a valid location.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have sourced the `setenv` script with

```
source setenv
```

before trying to run the configure script.

Also, why not use OMNeT++ 5.7 ?